# Looping through sequence objects in a list?

Tags: r, data-manipulation, traminer

I have a list that contains 24 `TraMineR` sequence objects. Now I want to calculate the Optimal Matching distances for each of these sequence objects (only within each object) and store it in a new list, now consisting of 24 OM distance objects (distance matrices).

The dataset can be found [here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3674946/event-stream-20-l-m.csv).

```
library(TraMineR)
sequences <- read.csv(file = "event-stream-20-l-m.csv", header = TRUE, nrows=10)
repo_names = colnames(sequences)

# 1. Loop across and define the 24 sequence objects & store them in sequence_objects
colpicks <- seq(10,240,by=10)
sequence_objects <- mapply(function(start,stop) seqdef(sequences[,start:stop]), colpicks-    9, colpicks)

# 2. Calculate the costs for OM distances within each object 
costs <- mapply(seqsubm(sequence_objects, method="TRATE"))

# 3. Calculate the OM distance objects for each sequence object
sequences.om <- seqdist(sequence_objects, method="OM", indel=1, sm=costs, with.missing=FALSE, norm="maxdist")
```

Step (1) works fine, but when I progress to step (2), it tells me:

```
Error in seqsubm(sequence_objects, method = "TRATE") : 
[!] data is NOT a sequence object, see seqdef function to create one
```

This is natural, because `sequence_objects` is not a sequence object, but a list of sequence objects.

How can I apply the `seqsubm` function to a list of sequence objects?

Comment: Just voting to close without suggesting how the question can improve is not very constructive...

Comment: I suspect those are votes to migrate this question, because it is likely to get better attention on SO. I do have one suggestion for improvement, though: please reread the code and error message carefully, because `sequences_objects` in the error message does not literally match `sequence_objects` in the code--something is strange about that.

Comment: Corrected - now it has the right error message.

Comment: With regards to moving, could someone add the `traminer` tag to SO - it would be helpful as a way for the maintainers of the TraMineR package to catch all questions relevant to them.

Comment: @histelheim, can you please post sample data for `sequences`.  thanks

Comment: The syntax for mapply is `mapply(function, list1, list2, MoreArgs=list(...) )`. With no data it will be difficult to guess where you further errors might be but certainly your current call is malformed.

Comment: Here is the dataset: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3674946/event-stream-20-l-m.csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `TraMineR` package, however it looks like you are trying to iterate over the elements of `sequence_objects`.

`mapply` is for iterating over multiple objects simultaneously.
`lapply` in contrast is for iterating over a single object.

Therefore, the following might work for you:

```
 costs <- lapply(sequence_objects, seqsubm, method="TRATE")
```

Comment: This returns `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
   [!] data is NOT a sequence object, see seqdef function to create one` which is strange, since in step 1 the `seqdef` function has been applied in what to me seems a successful manner

Comment: Try adding `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` to the `mapply` statement in step 1.