# Using mapply to create sequence objects in R/TraMineR?

Tags: r, traminer

I am running the code below to generate a list of `TraMineR` sequence objects. The dataset can be found [here][1].

```
library(TraMineR)
sequences <- read.csv(file = "event-stream-20-l-m.csv", header = TRUE, nrows=10)
repo_names = colnames(sequences)

# 1. Loop across and define the 24 sequence objects & store them in sequence_objects
colpicks <- seq(10,240,by=10)
sequence_objects <- mapply(function(start,stop) seqdef(sequences[,start:stop]),
                           colpicks - 9, colpicks)
```

However, if I run:

```
test <- sequence_objects[1]
seqdist(test, indel=1, with.missing=FALSE, norm="maxdist")
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Error:  [!] data is not a state sequence object, use 'seqdef' function to create one
```

How can it be that the `mapply` using `seqdef` does *not* create a list of sequence objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looping through sequence objects in a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15839403/looping-through-sequence-objects-in-a-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mapply` by default simplifies the return value.

As per the comment in the previous question, try including `SIMPLIFY=FALSE` in the `mapply` call.